# How can I look for objects with missing value or None as key?

Tags: plone, zope, catalog

I would like to perform a search on the zope catalog of the objects with missing index key values. Is it possible?

For example consider the subsequent code lines:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
results = catalog.searchResults({'portal_type': 'Event', 'review_state': 'pending'})
```

what to do if I'm interested in objects in which a certain item, instead of portal_type or review_state, has not be inserted?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ZCatalog/3.0a2 -- latest zcatalog provides support for "not" queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search for both types, but to search for `MissingValue` entries requires custom handling of the internal catalog data structures.

Indexes take the value from an object, and index that. If there is an `AttributeError` or similar, the index does not store anything for that object, and if the same field is part of the returned columns, in that case a `MissingValue` will be given to indicate the index is empty for that field.

In the following examples I assume you have a variable `catalog` that points to the site's portal_catalog tool; e.g. the result of `getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')` or similar.

### Searching for None

You can *search* for None in many indexes just fine:

```py
catalog(myKeywordIndex=None)
```

The problem is that most indexe types ignore `None` as a value. Thus, searching for `None` will fail on Date and Path indexes; they ignore None on index, and Boolean indexes; they turn None into False when indexing.

Keyword indexes ignore `None` as well, unless it is part of a sequence. If the indexed method returns `[None]` it'll happily be indexed, but `None` on it's own won't be.

Field indexes do store `None` in the index.

Note that each index can show unique values, so you can check if there are `None` values stored for a given index by calling:

```py
catalog.uniqueValuesFor(indexname)
```

### Searching for missing values

This is a little trickier. Each index does keep track of what objects it has indexed, to be able to remove data from the index when the object is removed, for example. At the same time, the catalog keeps track of what objects it has indexed as a whole.

Thus, we can calculate the difference between these two sets of information. This is what the catalog does all the time when you call the published APIs, but for this trick there is no such public API. We'll need to reach into the catalog internals and grab these sets for ourselves.

Luckily, these are all BTree sets, and the operations are thus relatively efficient. Here is how I'd do it:

```py
from BTrees.IIBTree import IISet, difference

def missing_entries_for_index(catalog, index_name):
    # Return the difference between catalog and index ids
    index = catalog._catalog.getIndex(index_name)
    referenced = IISet(index.referencedObjects()) # Works with any UnIndex-based index
    return (
        difference(IISet(catalog._catalog.paths), referenced),
        len(catalog) - len(referenced)
    )
```

The `missing_entries_for_index` method returns an IISet of catalog ids and it's length; each is a pointer to a catalog record for which the named index has no entry. You can then use `catalog.getpath` to turn that into a full path to objects, or use `catalog.getMetadataForRID` to get a dictionary of metadata values, or use `catalog.getobject` to get the original object itself, or use `catalog._catalog[]` to get catalog brains.

The following method will give you a catalog result set, just like you would get from a regular catalog search:

```py
from ZCatalog.Lazy import LazyMap

def not_indexed_results(catalog, index_name):
    rs, length = missing_entries_for_index(catalog, index_name)
    return LazyMap(catalog._catalog.__getitem__, rs.keys(), length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ago. Actually reading the link you suggest I discover that it's not possible without a trick. I report from pypi:

> Note that negative filtering on an index still restricts items to those having a value in the index. So with 10 documents, 5 of them in the foo index with a value of 1, a query for not 1 will return no items instead of the 5 items without a value. You need to index a dummy/default value if you want to consider all items for a particular index.

So it is necessary to give a default value to your item and look for it.